# How can I set an attribute in every subdocument in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

If I have a document like:

```
{title: "hello", 
 formats:{mp4: {status: "processing"},
          webm: {status: "processing" }} }
```

How can I write a $set query to set both inner status to "completed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rework your schema to be something like:

```
{
  "title":"Hello",
  "formats":[{
      "format":"mp4",
      "status":"processing",
  },
   {
      "format":"mp4",
      "status":"processing",
  }
  ]
 }
```

That way you aren't forcing a particular label and have a more abstract schema. You would have to still touch each of the status, there isn't an update all for them.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update({title: "hello"}, {
    $set: {
        "formats.mp4.status": "complete", 
        "formats.webm.status": "complete"}
    })
```

Comment: this is the answer though, I like the document re-structured by @Frederico

Comment: thanks, i was looking for a command to set every document in an array. If i were to add another format, the $set cmd would not work.